# Invalid Deployment Descriptors in Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

i am working on Java project ,which is using GlassFish server.there is no error in project but when i tried to run it ,it is showing this error_

```
SEVERE: DPL8015: Invalid Deployment Descriptors in Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web]. 
Line 9 Column 22 -- cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'description'. No child element is expected at this point.
SEVERE: DPL8005: Deployment Descriptor parsing failure : cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'description'. No child element is expected at this point.
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'description'. No child element is expected at this point.
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:612)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'description'. No child element is expected at this point.
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:304)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:225)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:614)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:366)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:148)
```

whats went wrong, is anybody face this issue ?

```
Discriptor
<context-param>
    <param-name>tiles-definitions</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
    <description> Tiles configuration definition files and a listener need to be defined. the
        listener will initialize JspTilesViewHandlerImpl with tiles definitions. 
    </description>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Can we see the relevant deployment descriptor ?

Comment: Did you try validating your web.xml against the schema/dtd?

Comment: web.xml is the deployment descriptor

Comment: Search for this location in your project: - `WEB-INF/web.xml`

Comment: Search for the tag: - `description` and paste the near by codes..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to [javaee](http://schemas.stylusstudio.com/j2ee50/n7e2eaf6a/complexType_param-valueType.html) the `description` tag should be the first tag not the last one

Comment: when i used this project with Eclipse it is showing error Like this_  
_Unable to resolve JRE: mustang (Standard VM)_  when i go to project>>properties>>libraries

Comment: is this related to the same question?

Comment: yes, when i used netBeans it is showing above error at the time of run, and in Eclipse it is showing this  Unable to resolve JRE: mustang (Standard VM)