# Invalid deployment descriptor error in NetBeans

Tags: java, struts2, netbeans-7

I'm trying to learn web development using Java.
I have to mention, I didn't open a new project, I'm working on an existing one and trying to add pages to it.

I am using netbeans IDE 7.2.1 to create a servlet. I also use Struts2. I right-click on a the package in which I want to create the servlet in, New,  Servlet. Then a popup window appears to prompt me for the Class Name, location, etc. At the bottom of the popup, it says in red:

**Invalid deployment descriptor web.xml**

And doesn't allow me to continue. 
When I opened my web.xml file I could not see anything which might seems to be related to my issue. 
Can someone please help?

Edit:

1. I am really a newbie :) Sorry about the silly questions.
2. When I run this page, I get the error page of our website, meaning ( I assume ) it look the file somewhere and is not being able to find it.

Thank you again...

Comment: can you share your web.xml

Comment: Sadly I can't, It's a project from my work.

Comment: You can Check whether you get any SaxParserException? Check if the XML is well formed you didn't leave any tags unmatched.

Comment: @Rimchik can you share the schema tag alone that is the first tag of the web.xml

Comment: @Rimchik show your war package structure

Comment: @Lakshmi The schema tag is: <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"> and the xml file is not written by me, it was there and works fine with other pages.

Comment: @Lakshmi I tried to validate my xml file and got the following msg: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'url-pattern'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":dispatcher}' is expected. [23]

Comment: @Rimchik please post you complete error log. That can atleast help to solve the problem without seeing the code we can only guess what might be wrong. Check these links if anything helps you http://apache-geronimo.328035.n3.nabble.com/servlet-mapping-in-web-xml-td328311.html  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12893675/2006839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the semicolon you have in the tag

change it to

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Comment: The problem was I ignored the Struts framework. I was supposed to add an Action and not a Servlet. This was also the reason I could not see anything related to Servlets tags and saw only filter tags. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR HELPING!!

Comment: @Rimchik good that you got the problem but indeed there was a problem with the descriptor tag too.. so hope my answer also helped you.. you can vote up my answer if it was useful. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Struts framework, you should be adding Actions and not Servlets. 
The web.xml file will contain filter tags and not Servlet tags as expected without the Struts.